# Email rules jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Best,

I would like to use the jQuery validation (plugin), now I get the email rules not properly put. Can anyone help me?

Bert

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});
$("#contactFormm").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        // 'this' refers to the form
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1 ? 'Er is 1 veld niet (correct) ingevuld' : 'Er zijn ' + errors + ' velden niet (correct) ingevuld.';
            $("div.error span").html(message);
            $("div.error").show();
        } else {
            $("div.error").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Show the HTML markup of your form and explain what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Your code appears to be working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/fB9p4/

Comment: Do you realize that `debug: true` will block the form from submitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `field`

```
field: {
    required: true,
    email: true
}
```

To `email`

```
email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
}
```

`field` means your field name. So assuming your will be `<input name="email" />`

Full Code:

```
$("#contactFormm").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        // 'this' refers to the form
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1 ? 'Er is 1 veld niet (correct) ingevuld' : 'Er zijn ' + errors + ' velden niet (correct) ingevuld.';
            $("div.error span").html(message);
            $("div.error").show();
        } else {
            $("div.error").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Since the OP did not show his HTML markup, your answer is nothing but a blind guess.  How do you know the misspelling in his `"#contactFormm"` selector isn't the real problem or another problem?  Until we see the relevant HTML, his code is already working:  http://jsfiddle.net/fB9p4/

Comment: @Sparky OP wants to validate the email field, so thats why i assume the input name will be `email` instead of `field`. And what do you mean by "misspelling in his `"#contactFormm"` selector "

Comment: You can't see his HTML so the field may be named `field` just as he programmed it and the problem may be that his `form` has `id="contactForm"`.  Notice how "Form" is not misspelled as "Formm".  Without seeing his HTML we're just making guesses.  Get it?

Comment: If you're posting _blind_ guesses as answers, you're not really using this site correctly.  Most of the time, answers are only posted when the OP shows enough code to see the actual problem.  If the OP doesn't show enough code to replicate the problem, [his question is considered "off-topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and IMO should not be answered until he fixes it.  That's why I haven't posted his misspelled "Formm" selector as an answer... because if it's misspelled in both places then it's _not_ the problem.